# iphone: CLLocation manager delegate method is not called on click of a button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

one more bad day god knows whats the problem with this but delegate methods for CLLocation Mangaer are not called once I click a refresh button, on click of this button I ask location manager to update location

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"failed");
```

}

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{


NSLog(@"current lat= %f and long=%f ", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

NSDate *eventDate = newLocation.timestamp; 
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

if (abs(howRecent) < 10) {

    [lat setText:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude]];
    [lon setText:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude]];

}

else {
    [lat setText:@"Not changed"];
    [lon setText:@"Not changed"];
}

}

  -(IBAction) refrechLoc{

NSLog(@"updating location");
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}
Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is beginning updating on `viewWillAppear`, so it won't update the location until it is not stopped by `stopUpdatingLocation`. If you want to restart updating you should call `stopUpdatingLocation` before `startUpdatingLocation`:

```
-(IBAction) refrechLoc{
    NSLog(@"updating location");
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

*imho, there is no need in location updating restart in general*

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty damn useless. Why suggest it if there's no need to do it?

Comment: I couldn't imagine why should one restart the updating but maybe there is some logic behind the provided sample code? :)

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how `CLLocationManager` works. The delegate is called when `CLLocationManager` has a new location for you. `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` merely tells the location manager to start updating the location, so there's no need to call that twice.

**EDIT:** For clarity: The delegate is called when the location is updated, i.e., when the device has moved.